# Populate Data in Right Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in long format. I want to convert it to wide format. First row should go to first column, second row to 2nd column, third row to 3rd column. Similarly 4th row to first column and so on. I did this but some rows have data missing so loop should skip that row. Logic to figure out column mapping -
First column must have word 'bed', second column must have word 'm^2', third column must have word either 'floor' or 'lift'.

```
Type <- read.table(header = F, text = "
2bed
197m²
Floor5exteriorwithlift
3bed
103m²
Groundfloorexteriorwithlift
3bed
110m²
4bed
195m²
Floor5exteriorwithlift
")

Type2 = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(Type)) {
  
  # Counter
  j = ceiling(i/3)
  
  if(i %% 3 == 1) {
    Type2[j,"BedRoom"] = Type[i,]
  }
  else if(i %% 3 == 2) {
    Type2[j,"Size"] = Type[i,]
  }
  else  Type2[j,"Floor"] = Type[i,]
  
}
```

Desired output should be as follows -

[image]

Full Dataset link - https://sites.google.com/site/pocketecoworld/testing.csv

Comment: yes, will have always same pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of 'bed' substring in column 'V1', grouped by that variable, create the column name column making use of the `row_number` as index to replace with a `vector` of strings, then use `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
Type %>%
     group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(V1, '^\\d+\\s*bed$'))) %>% 
     mutate(colnm = c('BedRoom', 'Size', 'Floor')[row_number()]) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = V1) %>%
     select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  BedRoom Size  Floor                      
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr>                      
#1 2bed    197m² Floor5exteriorwithlift     
#2 3bed    103m² Groundfloorexteriorwithlift
#3 3bed    110m² <NA>                       
#4 4bed    195m² Floor5exteriorwithlift
```

---

Using the OP's original data

```
dat1 %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(V1, '^\\d+\\s*bed$'))) %>% 
  mutate(colnm = c('BedRoom', 'Size', 'Floor')[row_number()]) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = V1)  %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 30 x 3
#   BedRoom Size        Floor                          
#   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>                          
# 1 4 bed   "160 m\xb2" Floor 3 exterior with lift     
# 2 7 bed   "899 m\xb2" <NA>                           
# 3 7 bed   "710 m\xb2" <NA>                           
# 4 4 bed   "320 m\xb2" Floor 8 exterior with lift     
# 5 4 bed   "326 m\xb2" Floor 2 exterior with lift     
# 6 4 bed   "153 m\xb2" Floor 12 exterior with lift    
# 7 2 bed   "158 m\xb2" Floor 5 exterior with lift     
# 8 3 bed   "275 m\xb2" Ground floor exterior with lift
# 9 3 bed   "136 m\xb2" Floor 2 exterior with lift     
#10 6 bed   "623 m\xb2" <NA>                           
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: In my bigger dataset, it is throwing error - Values in `V1` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

Comment: @john I think you can use `%>% mutate(rn = rowid(grp)) %>%` before the `pivot_wider`

Comment: rowid function from which package? any alternative of rowid in dplyr or base?

Comment: @john In that case, you can use `Type %>%
     group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(V1, '^\\d+bed$'))) %>% 
     mutate(colnm = c('BedRoom', 'Size', 'Floor')[row_number()], rn = row_number()) %>% ungroup %>% pivot_wider(names_from = colnm, values_from = V1)`

Comment: Thanks. It's creating 4 variables - BedRoom, Size, Floor and NA. From 4th row, everything is falling under NA. Seems very close

Comment: @john can you post an example that shows the issue so that i can test it

Comment: Dataset link - https://sites.google.com/site/pocketecoworld/testing.csv

Comment: @john I looked at the data. THere are some spaces between the digits and bed.  Can you test the updated code

Comment: Sorry for one more request. Code fails if "bed" is skipped in any iteration. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @john I would say that there are other cases also where this can be problematic.  I.e. if two of the entries are not present which can be any combinations.  Can you post a new question with a better example because the condition you mentioned would be more complex

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Any help would be highly appreciated on the same.

Comment: @john This solution is based on the pattern I assumed to be present in your original data.  It is also possible that the order of occurrence can be reversed and this can cause lot of issues

Comment: @john can you please post as a new question with a better example so that the conditions can be changed.  The way you described, it seems a complex case

Comment: sure, will post as a new question